# Using Xpath to retrieve nodes satisfying a certain criteria, based on attribute values

Tags: xpath, attributes

```
<AgoraServersConfig>
  <AgoraServers id="NYQ1">
    <AgoraName>prod</AgoraName>
    <TableName>someTable</TableName>
    <Rule_ID>1</Rule_ID>
    <Rule_ID>3</Rule_ID>
    <Rule_ID>5</Rule_ID>
  </AgoraServers>
  <AgoraServers id ="QA03">
    <AgoraName>dev</AgoraName>
    <TableName>someTable</TableName>
    <Rule_ID>1</Rule_ID>
    <Rule_ID>2</Rule_ID>
    <Rule_ID>5</Rule_ID>
  </AgoraServers>
</AgoraServersConfig>
```

Given the above schema, I would like to know how to frame an Xpath query that returns the children of the node whose id is "QA03", for example.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Good Question, +1. See my answer for two complete solutions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

**`/*/*[@id='QA03']/node()`**

It is also possible to use the standard XPath function [**`id()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-id).

However, for this to work, there must be a DTD for the XML document that defines `id` as an [**"ID-type attribute"**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-TokenizedType).

**Example**: `id('QA03')/node()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your schema, but to return children of a node based on that node's id attribute would look something like

```
//*[@id='QA03']/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath would look like this:

```
/AgoraServersConfig/AgoraServers[@id='QA03']/*
```

If you wanted to do something a bit more dynamic, you could put the id into a variable, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="targetid">QA03</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="/AgoraServersConfig/AgoraServers[@id=$targetid]/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thanks olly, i went with your 'static' xpath...worked well :)